# A Maven plugin 1.8.3 to support App Engine requires Maven version 3.1.0

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, pom.xml, appengine-maven-plugin

Could someone compile this pom.xml from this tutorial: 
https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/

I tried as well this one, but I'm not familiar wtih 'maven invoker plugin configuration' and settings.xml

https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/source/browse/pom.xml

The error I'm getting is the following:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.3:devserver (default-cli) on project nerinorestaurante: The p
lugin com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.3 requires Maven version 3.1.0 -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your intention is to use the appengine-maven-plugin?
If so, you need to use version 3.1 of maven.  Download it, install it.

It is all clearly explained here : http://maven.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Appengine requires JDK 7 (not 8 or 9, for example).

Set JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME environment variables. E.g.:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
```